# how to parse JSON value store in variable, using flutter dart

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

how to API response data store in the variable.

```
             var result = await http.get(apiUr); 
             dynamic responseJson = json.decode(result.body)['Data'];
             dynamic  resultResponse = responseJson['Result'];
             dynamic responseMsg = responseJson['Msg'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this : https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/
for convert json response to dart and then

```
var res = <classname>.fromjson(jsonDecode(result));
```